# Creating conceptual models and relations

Tags: sql, database, database-design, uml, entity-relationship

I am new to databases and I am trying to learn to design them. I am trying to understand creating conceptual models and transforming them to relations.

My example:

A building has three rooms - room 1, room 2, and room 3. Rooms 2 and 3 have chairs in them but not the room 1. The maximum allowed number of people in rooms 2 and 3 equals to the number of chairs in those rooms.

I am aware this is probably very basic for someone experienced. However, I am trying to find a solution for it and the other threads have not helped.

The question is: When creating a conceptual model for the above description, the number of chairs and the capacity of individual rooms will represent attributes of child tables (room 2 and room 3) or the parent table (building).

[image: conceptual model]

Comment: The capacity of the individual rooms should be a column on the `Rooms` table, but there should only be one single table for all of the rooms, as opposed to a separate table for each.

Comment: I added an image of a sample of the diagram I was thinking this could look like.

Comment: The model you showed is using Generalization which can be read as "is a". It means that `room 1`, `room 2` and `room 3` are all a kind of `Building`, which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: @Geert Bellekens no you are right. Thank you for pointing it out. What I meant was following: a building has rooms and a room can be room1, room2, or room3. I updated the diagram.

Comment: No No, room1, room2 and room3 should probably be instances of the class Room, and not subclasses. In general we don't mix classes and instances on the same diagram (although nobody forbids it). You could make a class diagram showing only Building and Room (usually relations like that are modeled using a composition) and make a separate object diagram showing the instances or Room with their run-state values for RoomID and Capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good use of roles in a composite structure diagram. See the answer to [Difference between instances and roles in UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119279/difference-between-instances-and-roles-in-uml/34120727#34120727) .